# An example on using command line arguments to get user input

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

So in class, we just learned how to convert String into int using parsing. And we were given this question that is summarized in the title. So if the user inputs, for example, "HI" in the interactions panel; he/she will get an output. How would this code look like i.e. we're not allowed to use the Scanner class? I'm not really sure if I'm making something easy to understand complicated. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The command line arguments are passed as `String[] args` array to the `main()` method. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What's the "interactions panel"?

Comment: try a google search for `BufferedReader` and `System.in`. there should be plenty of resources.

Comment: Manu - The interaction panel is where you interact with the code in java

Comment: Cinnam - Yes but I'm not really sure how to use that to get user input.

Comment: @LivingLegend That's just for command line arguments (see SSH's answer). If you want the user to enter some input while the application is running, you have to read from `System.in`, which is what e.g. `Scanner` can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you simply use command line argument that is string

```
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
                System.out.println("Your command line argument is : "+args[0]);
                }
            }
```

`args[]` will hold your command line arguments which you can use in your main program as per your requirement. If it is integer than you must have to parse it as you said you have studied

Now you run it like this

```
$java Foo stackoverflow
```

**Output:**

> Your command line argument is : stackoverflow